# Is it possible to alert a witch by talking loud on microphone?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

I've been hearing rumors that it's possible to provoke a witch by talking louder than a certain volume level, so me and friends always go hush-hush around witches.

Is it true or is it just another fun element to the game the community came up with?

Comment: Never happened when playing the game on PC on steam. Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: My friends and family don't usually use in game chat, preferring to use something like Mumble or Skype.  Having said that, I would not be surprised if Valve hooked the microphone into the AI Director.

Comment: @MBraedley That would be lovely. It would make my day to see all of the mic spammers and music players getting swarmed by infected.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To give this question a test, I opened up a multiplayer session with a friend. We were using in-game chat, and approached what I can only imagine would be "earshot" of the Witch (basically as close as we could get without her tearing our faces off.) We then both proceeded to yell as loud as we could, for over a minute at differing volume levels, in an attempt to prove this theory.

Alas, doing this produced no results. We only succeeded in screaming like morons for a few minutes. It's also worth noting that we were running no mods, no extras, etc. Maybe the functionality for waking her up with voice is based in a mod?

At any rate, my personal experience resulted in a "No", and a Google search on the topic turned up few relevant results (mostly the same question being asked with no answers.)

Hope this helped. (Feel free to try for yourself. :P)

Comment: I guess it was so fun to think that this was true that me and my friends wanted to believe it. I expect Valve to add this feature to the next game.